# I want to improve the speed of query statements, but I want to know how

Tags: mysql, sql

When executing a query statement, the speed is very slow.

```
          SELECT
                T1.APPL_SEQ
                , T1.COMP_CD
                , (SELECT COMP_NM FROM tb_company WHERE COMP_CD = T1.COMP_CD) AS COMP_NM
                , T1.GPROD_CD
                , (SELECT GPROD_NM FROM tb_gprod WHERE GPROD_CD = T1.GPROD_CD) AS GPROD_NM
                , T1.SITE_CD
                , (SELECT SITE_NM FROM tb_site WHERE SITE_CD = T1.SITE_CD) AS SITE_NM
                , T1.INFLOW_CD
                , T1.INFLOW_URL
                , T1.STATUS
                , T1.REG_DTM
                , DECRYPTO(T1.NAME) AS NAME
                , DECRYPTO(T1.HP) AS HP
                , ifnull(T1.AGE,T1.`115`) AS AGE
                , ifnull(T1.GENDER,T1.`116`) AS GENDER
                , ifnull(T1.MEMO,T1.`120`) AS MEMO
                , ifnull(T1.`105`,T1.`124`)  AS TIME
                , T1.`125` AS AGE_CHILD
                , T2.API_YN
                , T2.API_START_DT
                , T2.API_END_DT
                , T2.API_CD
                , T2.DATA_INFLOWCD
                , T2.CONFIRM_YN
                , T2.SALE_YN
                , T2.SALE_PRICE
                , T2.BREAKDOWN
                , T2.INPUT_DATE
                , T3.DIST_YN
                , T3.DIST_DT             
                ,(select ifnull((select timestampdiff(DAY, T11.REG_DTM,T1.REG_DTM) AS DIFF2REGTIME from tb_applicant T11 WHERE T11.HP = T1.HP AND T11.GPROD_CD = T1.GPROD_CD AND T11.REG_DTM < T1.REG_DTM order by T11.REG_DTM desc limit 1),-1)) AS HP2_COUNT                
                
            FROM
                tb_applicant T1
                LEFT JOIN mm_applicant T2
                    ON T1.APPL_SEQ = T2.APPL_SEQ
                LEFT JOIN dist_applicant T3
                    ON T1.APPL_SEQ = T3.APPL_SEQ
                LEFT JOIN tb_site T4
                    ON T4.site_cd = T1.SITE_CD and T4.comp_cd = T1.COMP_CD and T4.gprod_cd = T1.GPROD_CD
            WHERE 1=1
                AND T1.APPL_SEQ > 147293
                AND T4.is_use = 'Y'
                $Sql_Search
            ORDER BY
                $Sql_OrderBy
        ) U1
        , (SELECT @ROWNUM := 0) U2
    ) V1";
    
    ,(select ifnull((...),-1)) AS HP2_COUNT
```

This is part of why it's so slow.

This query calculates the number of months difference by comparing REG_DTM when the td_applicant table has the same data for HP, GPROD, and COMP.

I don't need to get the date difference, is there any way to improve the query speed?

Comment: Use `Explain` to see where you need an index

Comment: Official documentation of `EXPLAIN`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html

Comment: change part of query as bellow:

```
from (select * from tb_applicant where APPL_SEQ > 147293 ) T1
            LEFT JOIN mm_applicant T2
                ON T1.APPL_SEQ = T2.APPL_SEQ
            LEFT JOIN dist_applicant T3
                ON T1.APPL_SEQ = T3.APPL_SEQ
            LEFT JOIN (select * from tb_site where is_use = 'Y') T4
                ON T4.site_cd = T1.SITE_CD and T4.comp_cd = T1.COMP_CD and T4.gprod_cd = T1.GPROD_CD       
```

in this manner lesser row is participated in the process.
Also you can just select columns that you call in this query and leave others.

Comment: ,(select ifnull((select timestampdiff(DAY, T11.REG_DTM,T1.REG_DTM) AS DIFF2REGTIME from tb_applicant T11 WHERE T11.HP = T1.HP AND T11.GPROD_CD = T1.GPROD_CD AND T11.REG_DTM < T1.REG_DTM order by T11.REG_DTM desc limit 1),-1)) AS HP2_COUNT
    
  

The actual speed issue is shown here, and it is okay to remove the expression for calculating the date in the query statement.

Comment: You use 4 correlated subqueries in the output list. You must move them to the query source (FROM clause).

Comment: Also I cannot understand that is the goal of `(SELECT @ROWNUM := 0) U2` subquery - you use this user-defined variable nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem are those subselect in the select. As @Akina suggested, you should move them in FROM and make them as join.

They way you have done implies that each subselect is executed for each row returned by the main select.

You have 4 subselect that mean if you have 100 rows you execute 1 (main select) + (4*100) query so 401 instead of 1.

Using join allow the internal optimization engine to choose the best strategy to perform the query, in your way practically no optimization are applied.

I post a short example of how should be your query, didn't refactor the whole query since without database is a bit difficult to do it and I can easily produce a wrong query.

Notice that you select twice on tb_site with different condition, so is up to you to put the correct one.

```
SELECT T1.APPL_SEQ, T1.COMP_CD,  T1.GPROD_CD, T1.SITE_CD
       TC.COMP_NM,
       TG.GPROD_NM,
       TS.SITE_NM,
    ......
FROM tb_applicant T1
    LEFT JOIN mm_applicant T2
    JOIN tb_company TC on TC.COMP_CD = T1.COMP_CD
    JOIN tb_gprod TG on GPROD_CD = T1.GPROD_CD
    JOIN tb_site TS on TS.SITE_CD = T1.SITE_CD ON T1.APPL_SEQ = T2.APPL_SEQ
.......
```

Comment: How can I write the code if I want to remove all REG_DTM part from this part? ```

, (select ifnull((select timestampdiff(DAY, T11.REG_DTM,T1.REG_DTM) AS DIFF2REGTIME from tb_applicant T11 WHERE T11.HP = T1.HP AND T11.GPROD_CD = T1.GPROD_CD AND T11.COMP_CD = T1.COMP_CD AND T11.REG_DTM < T1.REG_DTM order by T11.REG_DTM desc limit 1),-1)) AS HP2_COUNT ```